# How to sort an angularFireCollection?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm having trouble sorting larger Arrays with an angularFireCollection binding:

```
$scope.offers = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url));
```

while having in my template the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="offer in offers | limitTo:100 | orderBy:'createdTimestamp':true">
```

While the offers.length is < 100, new items are correctly displayed on top. After 100 items, the sorting stops working at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your expression order. `"offer in offers | limitTo:100 | orderBy:'createdTimestamp':true"` first gets the first 100 elements of `offers`, then orders. What you want is to order, then limit, so you want to use the string `"offer in offers | orderBy:'createdTimestamp':true | limitTo:100"`. You can see what I mean in the following jsFiddle, where the first list limits the array and then tries ordering while the second orders, then limits: http://jsfiddle.net/qE5P9/1/.